# Which font is this?

Tags: font-identification

I want to know which font is used on this hoodie:

[image: http://www.almamaterstore.in/skin/frontend/default/blank/images/josephte/01.jpg]

Comment: some kind of collegiate font style

Comment: Could be one of these: http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=104

Comment: is the ninja wearing the hoodie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of these are an exact match, but many of them are very similar to that font:
http://www.fontspace.com/search/?q=jersey&text=JOSEPHITE&fontsize=80&foreground=000000&background=FFFFFF

I would say that this one is the closest, and would match almost exactly if you offset it in illustrator to make it a bit thicker:

http://www.fontspace.com/john-singer/schooldays

[image]

**EDIT:** Offset in Illustrator:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That really helps. Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.